# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError in pip install -r requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I am trying to create anaconda virtual environment using requirements.txt file. Details are as under I want to install tensorflow, keras and pytorch in my virtual environment but it was not working so I requested requirements.txt file, but it is giving me following error

```
        c:\temp\practice>conda create --prefix c:\temp\practice python=3.6
    WARNING: A directory already exists at the target location 'c:\temp\practice'
    but it is not a conda environment.
    Continue creating environment (y/[n])? y
    
    Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
    Solving environment: done
    
    ## Package Plan ##
    
      environment location: c:\temp\practice
    
      added / updated specs:
        - python=3.6
    
    
    The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
    
      certifi            pkgs/main/win-64::certifi-2020.12.5-py36haa95532_0
      pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-20.3.3-py36haa95532_0
      python             pkgs/main/win-64::python-3.6.12-h5500b2f_2
      setuptools         pkgs/main/win-64::setuptools-52.0.0-py36haa95532_0
      sqlite             pkgs/main/win-64::sqlite-3.33.0-h2a8f88b_0
      vc                 pkgs/main/win-64::vc-14.2-h21ff451_1
      vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.27.29016-h5e58377_2
      wheel              pkgs/main/noarch::wheel-0.36.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
      wincertstore       pkgs/main/win-64::wincertstore-0.2-py36h7fe50ca_0
      zlib               pkgs/main/win-64::zlib-1.2.11-h62dcd97_4
    
    
    Proceed ([y]/n)? y
    
    Preparing transaction: done
    Verifying transaction: done
    Executing transaction: done
    #
    # To activate this environment, use
    #
    #     $ conda activate c:\temp\practice
    #
    # To deactivate an active environment, use
    #
    #     $ conda d

eactivate
    
    
    c:\temp\practice>conda activate c:\temp\practice
    
    (c:\temp\practice) c:\temp\practice>
    (c:\temp\practice) c:\temp\practice>pip install -r requirements.txt
    Processing c:\ci\absl-py_1603889282672\work
    ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\ci\\absl-py_1603889282672\\work'
    
    
    (c:\temp\practice) c:\temp\practice>
```

My requirements.txt file is

```
absl-py @ file:///C:/ci/absl-py_1603889282672/work
aiohttp @ file:///C:/ci/aiohttp_1602512552257/work
alabaster==0.7.12
argh==0.26.2
argon2-cffi @ file:///C:/ci/argon2-cffi_1596826740294/work
astor==0.8.1
astroid @ file:///C:/ci/astroid_1592495992870/work
astunparse==1.6.3
async-generator==1.10
async-timeout==3.0.1
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/attrs_1604765588209/work
autopep8 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/autopep8_1596578164842/work
Babel==2.8.0
backcall==0.2.0
bcrypt @ file:///C:/ci/bcrypt_1597936262193/work
bleach @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/bleach_1600439572647/work
blinker==1.4
brotlipy==0.7.0
cachetools @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/cachetools_1596822027882/work
certifi==2020.6.20
cffi @ file:///C:/ci/cffi_1600681203656/work
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
cloudpickle @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/cloudpickle_1598884132938/work
colorama @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/colorama_1603211150991/work
cryptography @ file:///C:/ci/cryptography_1601046909128/work
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.4.2
defusedxml==0.6.0
diff-match-patch @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/diff-match-patch_1594828741838/work
docutils==0.16
entrypoints==0.3
flake8 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/flake8_1601911421857/work
future==0.18.2
gast==0.3.3
google-auth @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/google-auth_1604100403705/work
google-auth-oauthlib @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/google-auth-oauthlib_1603929124518/work
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio @ file:///C:/ci/grpcio_1597406495377/work
h5py==2.10.0
idna @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/idna_1593446292537/work
idna-ssl==1.1.0
imagesize==1.2.0
importlib-metadata @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/importlib-metadata_1602276842396/work
intervaltree @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/intervaltree_1598376443606/work
ipykernel @ file:///C:/ci/ipykernel_1596206775157/work/dist/ipykernel-5.3.4-py3-none-any.whl
ipython @ file:///C:/ci/ipython_1593446240034/work
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
isort @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/isort_1602603989581/work
jedi @ file:///C:/ci/jedi_1592841982010/work
Jinja2==2.11.2
joblib==0.17.0
jsonschema @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jsonschema_1602607155483/work
jupyter-client @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyter_client_1601311786391/work
jupyter-core==4.6.3
jupyterlab-pygments @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyterlab_pygments_1601490720602/work
Keras==2.3.1
Keras-Applications @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/keras-applications_1594366238411/work
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
keras-tuner==1.0.2
keyring @ file:///C:/ci/keyring_1601490935777/work
kiwisolver @ file:///C:/ci/kiwisolver_1603996656077/work
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
Markdown @ file:///C:/ci/markdown_1603216561566/work
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib @ file:///C:/ci/matplotlib-base_1603357981283/work
mccabe==0.6.1
med2image==2.2.4
mistune==0.8.4
mkl-fft==1.2.0
mkl-random==1.1.1
mkl-service==2.3.0
multidict @ file:///C:/ci/multidict_1600456490312/work
nbclient @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nbclient_1602783176460/work
nbconvert @ file:///C:/ci/nbconvert_1601896775581/work
nbformat @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nbformat_1602783287752/work
nest-asyncio @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nest-asyncio_1601499549014/work
nibabel==3.2.0
nilearn==0.7.0
notebook @ file:///C:/ci/notebook_1601498601160/work
numpy==1.18.5
numpydoc @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/numpydoc_1594166760263/work
oauthlib==3.1.0
olefile==0.46
opt-einsum==3.1.0
packaging==20.4
pandas==1.1.4
pandocfilters==1.4.2
paramiko @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/paramiko_1598886428689/work
parso==0.7.0
pathtools==0.1.2
pexpect==4.8.0
pfmisc==2.0.2
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow @ file:///C:/ci/pillow_1602785322033/work
pluggy==0.13.1
prometheus-client==0.8.0
prompt-toolkit @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/prompt-toolkit_1602688806899/work
protobuf==3.13.0
psutil @ file:///C:/ci/psutil_1598352185190/work
pudb==2019.2
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycodestyle==2.6.0
pycparser @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pycparser_1594388511720/work
pydicom==2.1.1
pydocstyle @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pydocstyle_1598885001695/work
pyflakes==2.2.0
Pygments @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pygments_1604103097372/work
PyJWT==1.7.1
pylint @ file:///C:/ci/pylint_1598624066230/work
PyNaCl @ file:///C:/ci/pynacl_1595009245871/work
pyOpenSSL @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pyopenssl_1594392929924/work
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyreadline==2.1
pyrsistent @ file:///C:/ci/pyrsistent_1600141799440/work
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-jsonrpc-server @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/python-jsonrpc-server_1600278539111/work
python-language-server @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/python-language-server_1600454544709/work
pytz==2020.1
pywin32==227
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
pywinpty==0.5.7
PyYAML==5.3.1
pyzmq==19.0.2
QDarkStyle==2.8.1
QtAwesome @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/qtawesome_1602272867890/work
qtconsole @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/qtconsole_1600870028330/work
QtPy==1.9.0
requests @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/requests_1592841827918/work
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rope @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/rope_1602264064449/work
rsa @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/rsa_1596998415516/work
Rtree==0.9.4
scikit-learn==0.23.2
scipy @ file:///C:/ci/scipy_1597675683670/work
Send2Trash==1.5.0
six==1.15.0
snowballstemmer==2.0.0
sortedcontainers==2.2.2
Sphinx @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sphinx_1597428793432/work
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.4
spyder @ file:///C:/ci/spyder_1599057304706/work
spyder-kernels @ file:///C:/ci/spyder-kernels_1599051725691/work
tabulate==0.8.7
tensorboard @ file:///home/builder/ktietz/conda/conda-bld/tensorboard_1604313476433/work/tmp_pip_dir
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.6.0
tensorflow==2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0
tensorflow-gpu==2.3.1
tensorflow-gpu-estimator==2.3.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.9.1
terminaltables==3.1.0
testpath==0.4.4
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
toml @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/toml_1592853716807/work
tornado==6.0.4
tqdm==4.54.0
traitlets==4.3.3
typed-ast==1.4.1
typing-extensions @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/typing_extensions_1598376058250/work
ujson @ file:///C:/ci/ujson_1602508243091/work
urllib3 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/urllib3_1603305693037/work
urwid==2.1.2
watchdog @ file:///C:/ci/watchdog_1593446204230/work
wcwidth @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/wcwidth_1593447189090/work
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.16.1
win-inet-pton==1.1.0
wincertstore==0.2
wrapt==1.11.2
yapf @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/yapf_1593528177422/work
yarl @ file:///C:/ci/yarl_1602696824692/work
zipp @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/zipp_1604001098328/work
```

Can you pl help and suggest ?

Thanks

Comment: The error states that `'C:\\ci\\absl-py_1603889282672\\work'` does not exist. Can you check? Also check if the correct permissions are set

Comment: yes set up right permissions installing on Windows 10 and run command prompt as Administrator Thanks

Comment: And the path exists also? There are also other paths in the same requirement.txt like `/tmp/build/80754af9/diff-match-patch_1594828741838/work` that do not look like they would be correct windows paths

Comment: Let me check in between can you try to install requirements.txt at your end too. Thanks

Comment: Any update? I will most certainly not be able to use your requirements.txt, because I don't have the locals files referenced by `file:`

Comment: Checked path looks like every thing looks good for me